# How do i add everything in my array together

Tags: python, arrays

In my code I am attempting to generate 8 random numbers using a for loop. I then add these to the end of my array of the name 'numbers'. Now I will like to add the numbers in this array together but I can't figure out a way to do this.
Below you will see my code.

```
    def get_key():
        numbers = []
        for i in range(8):
            i = random.randrange(33, 126)
            numbers.append(i)


    get_key()
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

sum(a) # outputs 15
```

Answer (score 0):

`add` as in `sum`? simply do `sum(numbers)`.

Comment: Thank you all very much this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can use `sum` to iterate and accumulate over the list (the default accumulator for `sum` is `int()`, i.e. `0`). Also, if this is the only purpose for the list, you can save memory by using a generator.

```
import random

get_key = lambda: sum(random.randrange(33, 126) for _ in range(8))
print( get_key() ) # 612
```

The real question is why are you trying to do this? It seems like there will be a more direct method by using a higher-level distribution. For example, the sum of n I.I.D. variables will approach a Normal distribution.